# How to cut corner with gentle slope?

Tags: css

I'm looking for cuting the bottom and bottom-left corner of div. Something like this http://prnt.sc/e93lif

Trying with help of `clip-path` 
But think it is not the good solution.

```css
#clip{
      width: 56px;
      height: 58.1px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      background-color: rgb(107, 170, 42);
      box-shadow: 0 2px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
    }
```

```html
<div id="clip"></div>
```

Comment: If you're trying to recreate that image, I would use an SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use a pseudo element to do the angled bit using skew.

```css
#clip {
  position: relative;
  width: 56px;
  height: 40px;
}
#clip, #clip:before {
  background-color: #6baa2a;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
#clip:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 32px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%) skewY(8deg);
  transform: translateY(50%) skewY(8deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="clip"></div>
```

Equally you could use an SVG: https://i.koya.io/GastelloIcon.svg

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 269.5"><path d="M256 248c0 13.2-10.7 22.7-23.8 21L23.8 243C10.7 241.3 0 229.2 0 216V24C0 10.8 10.8 0 24 0h208c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24V248z"/></svg>`

Answer (score 0):

you can set radius separately

```
div {
 width: 56px;
  height: 58.1px;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 28px;
  background-color: rgb(107, 170, 42);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}
```

you will get cut corner, won't be exactly  like your image.